# JAX-WS Web Services on Tomcat 8 – JAX-WS Library Files Location?

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, tomcat8

For a normal JSP web-app that provides web-services, where should the JAX-WS library jar files be placed?

```
<tomcat-home>/lib
```

or

```
<web-app>/WEB-INF/lib
```

and why?

In general, when are library files considered part of the container infrastructure or part of the web application?

**DETAILS**

I have implemented various JAX-WS web services following, among others, these guides:

https://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.10/docs

https://jaxenter.com/creating-soap-web-services-using-jax-ws-117689.html

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jws/jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/

http://www.java2blog.com/2013/03/jaxws-webservice-deployement-on-tomcat.html

Whilst the above guides were useful, there are differences in terms of both the required JAX-WS library jar files and where the JAX-WS library jar files should reside.

By trial and error, for JDK 1.8, Tomcat 8.0.30 & JAS-WS 2.2.10, this is the list of JAX-WS library jars that seem to be required:

```
gmbal-api-only.jar
ha-api.jar
jaxb-core.jar
jaxb-impl.jar
jaxws-api.jar
jaxws-rt.jar
management-api.jar
policy.jar
stax-ex.jar
streambuffer.jar
```

I am aware that the JDK contains some of the JAX-WS classes but these seem to be meant for standalone Java apps
ie all of the above jar files seem to be needed to avoid a ClassNotFoundException etc.

I have read the [Tomcat 8 class-loader how-to](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)

and appreciate that there is a parent-tree, hierarchal class loader and that jar files in:

```
<web-app>/WEB-INF/lib
```

- are only available to that web app ie are hidden from other web apps
- causes the app war file(s) to be bloated as each web app has it’s own copy

and that jar files in:

```
<tomcat-home>/lib
```

- are available to and shared by all web apps
- forces all web apps to use the same version of the library
- libraries must be inter web-app shareable ie no statics, thread-safe etc
- enables lookup via a JNDI Resource Factory eg JDBC, mail etc
- suppresses memory leaks for DriverManager eg JDBC

The web services seem to work when the JAX-WS library jar files are in either location.

Looking at the [Metro JAX-WS project](https://jax-ws.java.net),
where the JAX-WS library jars must be downloaded from, for now, I have put these into <tomcat-home>/lib as that is consistent with the ‘install’ option in the ant file.

As a general rule, I try not to pollute the web-container / app-server with unnecessary library jar files where possible as this can lead to conflicts for other web-apps that have to use a specific version of a required library.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue trying to deploy a web service to my local tomcat installation. I went the route of adding the jars you listed to get it going, but see the instructions of what's needed from Apache:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/extras.html#Web_Services_support_(JSR_109)

...which I think will go a long way to minimizing the amount of jars that end up in your Tomcat's lib folder.